# After Installing Visual Studio 2017 I am unable to debug in SQL Server Management Studio (SSMS)

Tags: sql-server, visual-studio, ssms, visual-studio-2017

After Installing VS2017 I am unable to debug queries in SQL Server Management Studio 2012 (SSMS). I keep getting the error:

> Unable to start program 'MSSQL:://YOUR_SERVER/YOUR_DATABASE/sys/=0'
>
> A Visual Studio DLL, coloader80.dll, is not correctly installed.
>   Please repair you Visual Studio installation via 'Add or Remove
>   Programs' in Control Panel.
>
> If the problem persis, you can manually register coloader80.dll from
>   the command prompt with 'regsvr32 "%CommonProgramFiles%\Microsoft
>   Shared\VS7Debug\coloader80.dll'

Answer (score 9):

From: [Developer Community](https://developercommunity.visualstudio.com/content/problem/25132/visual-studio-2017-install-breaks-sql-server-manag.html). 
To fix this issue, you can either:

Open a command prompt with administrator privileges and execute the following command:

```
reg add HKEY_CLASSES_ROOT\TypeLib{6A1A7D39-8449-4287-8EF0-CE256582C940}\8.0\0\win32 /t REG_SZ /d "C:\Program Files (x86)\Common Files\Microsoft Shared\VS7Debug\coloader80.tlb"
```

Alternatively you can execute:

```
regsvr32 "C:\Program Files (x86)\Common Files\Microsoft Shared\VS7Debug\coloader80.dll"
```

The correct registration will be included in future versions of Visual Studio.